emacs 28.2: how to delete the first 32 char of each Line
I need to delete the first 32 char of each line that compose my file.
Can someone explain me how to do that?
I've also read  How to delete the first few n chars of every line?
this answer, but didn't understand how to make it.
Can someone explain me better?

Please don't post a duplicate question just because you don't understand the original question and its accepted answer. If you need help understanding, maybe ask on a discussion site such as Reddit. Thx.

I've already tried the way that answer tell, but was unable, remember I'm on MAC and emacs 28.2
